# Pasting the same value quickly over a row

Tags: excel, loops, copy-paste, vba

A very easy question, but for some reason I am having a brain freeze. I have a individual value at the start of a row and wish to copy and paste this value over the next 300 cells. For argument sake, lets say "A:1" and the value is 1. We want to see "A:1" to "A:301" full of ones (or any other value we choose)...how do I do this without looping over each cell, such a loop would be:

```
   If Not IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")) Then
   Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Copy
   For k = 2 To 301
   Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, k).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
   Next
   Application.CutCopyMode = False
   End If
```

If its only 300 cells maybe a loop is acceptable, but for any larger number this becomes too slow. Please, help?!?!

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just this one line:

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 2),Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 301)).value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Value
```

Or you can use a `With` block and lessen the amount of typing:

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    .Range(.Cells(1, 2),.Cells(1, 301)).value = .Range("A1").Value
End With
```

Comment: Cheers boss. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No need for copy and paste - `Range("A1:A300").Value = Range("A1").Value` will do it

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
Sub dural()
    With Sheets(1)
        .Range("B1:KO1").Value = .Range("A1").Value
    End With
End Sub
```